# How can I obtain an IP address from my RPi access point?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

I have tried three different tutorials to attempt to set up my RPi as an wifi access point.

1. [Adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software)
2. [elinux](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot)
3. (Page one of) [sirlagz](http://sirlagz.net/2012/08/09/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-1/)

In all cases, I cannot connect properly to the RPi. I can see the wifi network from other devices, but my Android phone gets stuck on "Obtaining IP address…".

I know that my Ralink RT5370 should work. I have also attempted to follow the suggestions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/unable-to-obtain-ip-in-ap-mode/1626#1626) and manually start `udhcpd` or `dnsmasq` after the RPi obtains its wlan0 IP address. This did not help.

This is the output for (page one of) the third tutorial. In all cases, I can see `inet addr` for `wlan0` (but nothing for `mon.wlan0`).

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:43:fe:10  
          inet addr:192.168.1.91  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4373 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:320392 (312.8 KiB)  TX bytes:484473 (473.1 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:260 (260.0 B)  TX bytes:260 (260.0 B)

mon.wlan0 Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 7C-DD-90-41-31-35-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:393 (393.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7c:dd:90:41:31:35  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:60 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15182 (14.8 KiB)  TX bytes:10725 (10.4 KiB)
```

Contents of `/etc/iptables.ipv4.nat`

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sat Sep 28 10:59:25 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:338]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:338]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:260]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 28 10:59:25 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sat Sep 28 10:59:25 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [151:8950]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [145:15700]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 28 10:59:25 2013
```

Comment: Opening up ports 67 and 68 didn't help. I tried `sudo ufw allow 67:68/udp` and then `sudo ufw allow 67:68/tcp`. Only `sudo ufw disable` allowed internet connectivity from the wifi clients. I've edited the question to provide iptables configuration.

Comment: Perhaps add some logging to iptables to see where the packets are going ? You don't have any DROP or REJECT rules that would affect dhcp requests from what I can see. Also make sure your dhcp server is listening on the right interface as well

Comment: @Lawrence I realised that my final attempt only half followed the third tutorial. I had previously had problems with the first (wifi drivers) and the third was imprecisely written, so I started from scratch again with the second. After this tutorial, `sudo ufw allow 67:68/udp` allows the Pi to work as a AP. Thanks for your help. (I'm going give "solved" to N10 for suggesting the firewall (and ports) first, but I'll +1 you for your help.)

Comment: No problems. I should have thought about the firewall anyway :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problems when I was running this setup (but from Kali, not Raspbian).

Ensure your DHCP service is actually running. Mine would error out to the logs.

<s>Also make sure your firewall (if running) is allowing DHCP through.</s>

Your DHCP config file would be helpful for further information.

Comment: Oh that's funny… Your strike-out text helped! Disabling ufw fixed it. Do you know what I should enable so I can leave ufw on?

Comment: Using IPTables you can follow the directions on the following page [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/lettingdhcprequests.html). Ultimately you need to allow ports 67 and 68.

Comment: I'm going to reply in the comments to my question, since there are two of you suggesting similar things now.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 67:68/udp` fixes it, assuming I've followed the second tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

No IP Address for mon.wlan0 is normal.
What DHCP server are you using ?
Can you paste the config for the DHCP server ?
Assuming you're using Raspbian - What's the contents of /etc/network/interfaces ?
Have you disabled ifplugd ? ifplugd causes issues with hostapd.

Comment: I tried both `udhcpd` and `dnsmasq`. I essentially followed the guides to the letter. However, I've just realised that (as per the other answer) if I disable ufw it fixes the problem.

Comment: Sounds like your firewall is blocking DHCP requests then. UDP 67 and 68 need to be allowed in/out.

Comment: I'm going to reply in the comments to my question, since there are two of you suggesting similar things now.